# How can I make a simple admin page to change the content inside a p element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I just want to change the text inside a p element dynamically instead of manually changing the content by opening the html file itself

Comment: Tried with AJAX and Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: problem is i never tried ajax before and i am not sure what exactly to do with js

Answer (score 0):

You could try querying the text from a MySQL database. Here's a PoC:

Inside index.php you should have the code to query the DB and get your data.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM htmldata WHERE element='pobject'"; #SQL SELECT query 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pdata = $row['data'];
    }
} 
$conn->close();
?>

<html>
  <body>
    <p><?php echo $pdata; ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now here's the PHP code for admin.php.

Note: This is only the code that will receive a POST parameter and insert it in the database. You should include session checking so unauthorized users cannot edit the p data, and also make a frontend that will send the POST request.

**admin.php**

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['pdata'])){
  echo "No data passed";
}else{
    $pdata = $_POST['pdata'];
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "UPDATE htmldata SET data='$pdata' WHERE element='pobject'";  
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->close();  
}

?>
```